# Changing the contents of an external TextView on item click within ListView

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I am using a custom adapter for a ListView that displays a list of items that can be clicked and should change the text of an description TextView below the ListView. The description should display a descriptive text about the currently highlighted item.

In my Fragment containing the ListView and the TextView I used the following code to register an OnItemClickListener

**Java Code:**

```
    mTextView = (TextView) myParentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_select_option_desc_text_view);

    mListView = (ListView) myParentView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_select_option_list_view);
    mListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);

    mListView.setAdapter(new MyItemAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            int itemId = SelectStateFragment.this.mItems[position].getId();
            String description = DataStore.get().getItemDescription(itemId);

            SelectItemFragment.this.mTextView.setFocusable(true);
            SelectItemFragment.this.mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(description)); 

            SelectItemFragment.this.mSelectedPosition = position;

            view.setSelected(true);
        }
    });
```

**Fragment xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_select_option_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/list_view_background" >
    </ListView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_select_option_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stackFromBottom="true" 
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:fillViewport="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_select_option_desc_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3sp" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Item xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectable_item_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:padding="3sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:background="@drawable/selectable_item_background"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is: after I click on an item, the text view content gets updated as intended. However, I don't see any visual highlight of the selected item in my list view. Only if I click on the same item a second time my selection becomes visible as the item gets highlighted. The strange thing is: If I comment out the line

```
            SelectItemFragment.this.mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(description));
```

and therefore skip the update of the TextView, the selection immediately shows with the first click of an item.

Is there anything wrong with accessing other UI elements in an OnItemClickListener? Do I have to trigger some layout update after updating the TextView?

**Update: Inserted Sweety's suggestions into my code, added XML code**

Answer (score 0):

Try to set all items inside your list view to non focusable.

final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);

Also, make sure that for items inside list item set focusable false

android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
Also `view.setFocusable(true)` before setText.

Comment: The problem unfortunately stays the same :( I incorporated your changes into my posted code, I hope I understood everything correctly.